# Embed latest tweets from twitter onto a website

Tags: twitter, embed

I want to take the latest 5 tweets from a twitter and have it auto-update on a website. I read up on this a bit, and it looks like the only way to do it is to have a word press site. Any ideas? Thanks and let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This doesn't require WordPress at all. Where'd you hear that?]

Twitter themselves provide a [widget](https://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_profile) for doing this. It's somewhat limited in customization options. If you need more control over things like the appearance, there are bunches of jQuery plugins, like [Tweet](http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/), that'll give you just the data, which you can pump into custom markup/styling.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you don't need WordPress or any other specific CMS, technology or programming language.

If default widgets that were metioned by Su' are not enough, you may use your favourite language and use [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs) to fetch any number of tweets and update this list whenever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter integration has changed, read how to integrate tweets into your website at [Twitter Developer](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines).